# Why does getting the user input return None?

Tags: python

When I execute this python code, the answer gives me **"Hello none"** and doesn't give me a specific name. Ex. if my name was bob, I want it to say **"Hello Bob"** not **"Hello none"**

```
C1 = print(input("Hello player one, what is your name: "))

print("Hello" , C1)
```

Comment: Hint: what is the return value of the function `print`?

Comment: seems like you use python 3. it is better to mention it.
for python 2.7 (and below) you should use `raw_input`

Answer (score 3):

The `print()` function returns `None`. Remove the `print()` call, put that on a separate line instead:

```
C1 = input('Hello player one, what is your name: ')
print(C1)
print("Hello" , C1)
```

or leave it out altogether. The `input()` function itself *already* prints the question for you.

Answer (score 2):

`print` returns `None`. Remove it and you'll be fine:

```
C1 = input("Hello player one, what is your name: ")
```

Basically, you're assigning the value of `print(something)` to `C1`, and since `print` doesn't return anything, you're putting the value of `None` to `C1`. Hence `print('Hello', C1)` will result in `Hello None`.

Demo:

```
>>> C1 = input("Hello player one, what is your name: ")
Hello player one, what is your name: Bob
>>> print("Hello", C1)
Hello Bob
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be re-written as follows:

```
tmp = input("Hello player one, what is your name: ")
C1 = print(tmp)

print("Hello" , C1)
print("Hello", tmp) # that's what you probably want
```

The result you get from the `input` call is stored in `tmp`, the result of the `print` call is stored in `C1`. I assume that you'd like to obtain the input given by the user (i.e. the result of `input`). The result of `print` in python is simply `None`.