# Python: How do you print out "Correct!" instead?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
 # These lines print out the question, possible answers and a prompt for the user to input
  a string

 print("ART AND LITERATURE: Who painted Starry Night?")
 print("a. Vincent Van Gogh")
 print("b. Michelangelo")
 print("c. Leonardo Da Vinci")
 answer = print(input("Enter your choice:"))
 
# Semantic error: prints out 'a' and 'The correct answer was a' when input is 'a'
# Desired output: "Correct!" when input is 'a' and 'The correct answer was a' for other 
  inputs

 if answer == 'a':
    print("Correct!")

 else:
    print("The correct answer was a")
```

The first block of code prints out the question, possible answers, and a prompt for the user to input a string.

The if-else statement has a semantic error as it prints out "a" and "The correct answer was a" even when the input is indeed, "a".

How do I fix this so that "Correct!" is printed when the input is 'a' and 'The correct answer was a' for other inputs?

Comment: `answer = print(input("Enter your choice:"))` should be just `answer = input("Enter your choice:")`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does getting the user input return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330249/why-does-getting-the-user-input-return-none)

Comment: You could have checked by printing `answer` to see that it was None.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use `print` when using `input`.

Hence, just execute:

```
print("ART AND LITERATURE: Who painted Starry Night?")
print("a. Vincent Van Gogh")
print("b. Michelangelo")
print("c. Leonardo Da Vinci")
answer = input("Enter your choice:")

if answer == 'a':
    print("Correct!")

else:
    print("The correct answer was a")
```

OUTPUT:

```
ART AND LITERATURE: Who painted Starry Night?
a. Vincent Van Gogh
b. Michelangelo
c. Leonardo Da Vinci
Enter your choice:a
Correct!
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `answer = print(input("Enter your choice:"))` to `answer = input("Enter your choice:")` because the first one just prints the value  not to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
answer = print(input("Enter your choice:"))
```

You assigned a print statement to your answer variable, so when this line is executed, it prints what the user inputs too. Quick fix:

```
answer = input("Enter your choice:")
```

Comment: Actually, the original code assigned `None` to answer, because `print` returns None.